# Average-case complexity open problems other than one-way functions

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, average-case-complexity

The [list of unsolved problems in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_computer_science) on Wikipedia lists no problems in average-case complexity, except "Do one-way functions exist?" which is whether there is a polynomial time computable function that such that all efficient algorithms fail (with high probability) to invert it.

Are there other high-profile, specific open problems in average-case complexity?

Comment: First, I wouldn't call the existence of owf a problem about average complexity. If you are looking for similar questions check the list of open problems in crypto.

Comment: There's the planted clique conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planted_clique#As_a_hardness_assumption

Answer (score 6):

You can look at the [survey paper by Bogdanov and Trevisan](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0606037), and this [survey talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yo-naUur464) by Luca. The main open question is whether $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ implies that there exist hard on average problems in $\mathsf{NP}$. There are also more concrete conjectures about specific problems, two of which were mentioned in the comments:

- The [planted clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planted_clique): distinguish between a uniformly random graph on $n$ vertices, and a uniformly random graph in which we have planted a $k$-clique on a random $k$-subset of the vertices. Conjectured to be hard for $k = \omega(\log n)$, $k = o(\sqrt{n})$.
- [Feige's random SAT hypothesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.3.8586&rep=rep1&type=pdf): for every $\Delta$, any polynomial time algorithm which never refutes a satisfiable 3SAT formula will fail to refute most 3SAT formulas with $\Delta n$ clauses. It is consistent with current knowledge that this hypothesis may hold even up to $\Delta = o(\sqrt{n})$.